# Push javascript array back to server via a form?

Tags: javascript, tornado

How can I push a js variable back to the server?

for example, I have an array:

[image]

I am trying to find a way to push this array back to the server and save it as a CSV file. I am using a Python back end.

Comment: convert it into json string and then send it to server

Comment: Send an AJAX response with the data encoded as JSON and decode it on the server.

Comment: I have tried the following... http://jsfiddle.net/LLhTC/

Comment: @DataByDavid—much better to post your code here. And since you seem to be using a library, better add a tag for it here too.